# Remove white background from Custom paint in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I was checking out the Custom painter in flutter, I want to know how to remove the white background from it as shown in the attached image

**custom paint as bottom navigation**
[image: custom paint as bottom navigation]

this is how I implement it

```dart
    class BNBCustomPainter extends CustomPainter {
    final double height;
    BNBCustomPainter({
    required this.height,
    });
    @override
    void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    // final rect = offset & size,

    Paint paint = Paint()
      // ..color = Colors.green.withOpacity(0.2)
      ..style = PaintingStyle.fill
      // ..blendMode = BlendMode.clear
      ..shader = ui.Gradient.linear(
        Offset(0, 0),
        Offset(0, 10),
        [
          Color(0xff0093E9),
          Color(0xff80D0C7),
          // color2,
        ],
      );

    Path path = Path();
    path.moveTo(0, height); // Start
    path.quadraticBezierTo(size.width * 0.5, 0, size.width, height);
    path.lineTo(size.width, size.height);
    path.lineTo(0, size.height);
    path.lineTo(0, height);
    canvas.saveLayer(Offset.zero & size, Paint());
    canvas.restore();
    canvas.drawShadow(path, Colors.black, 5, true);
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
    }

    @override
    bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return false;
   }
}
```

Comment: can you give your code for bottom navigation bar container?

Comment: @AkbarMasterpadi i don't get the transparent look . if i set a color it works but this not what i hant to do

Comment: i used this and the same problem

Comment: bottomNavigationBarTheme:
                BottomNavigationBarThemeData(backgroundColor: Colors.blue)),

Comment: Hello, are you putting the painter inside of a `BottomNavigationBar()`? That might be what's creating the white background

Comment: Can you include `bottomNavigationBar:` widget?